# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Virtual Machine on VirtualBox not able to use network

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machines

Hey all, no matter what Network Adapter I use on VirtualBox for my newly setup Ubuntu VM, I cannot get a valid IP when I do ipconfig. All I get is a loopback address. Does anyone know what I would do to fix this and which Network Adapter in VirtualBox I would use to properly connect to my actual PC (host) and the outside world?

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone with the same problem this is how you would do this:
change eth0 to eth1 in /etc/network/interfaces, and choose the bridged network.

Comment: The proper way would be to first check your available interfaces with `ifconfig -a` and then configure the appropriate interface. FYI: In your case, the kernel renames the interface to eth1 during bootup because of the persistent-net-rules in udev.